# Ruby on Rails Stop Profanity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, profanity

I am creating a cinema site using Ruby on Rails and am adding in a review system. I want to stop users from swearing in their reviews and have tried the following gems to do so:

```
validates_decency_of

NoNo

Fu-Fu
```

The only thing that has come close is using exclusion:

```
validates :review_text, :exclusion => { :in => %w(shit fuck fucking twat bitch), :message => "you must not enter swear words"}
```

But the problem with this is that it will only work against reviews that have only those words, e.g. if you type "shit film" it will allow it but it will not allow the single word "shit".

Can someone please help.

review.rb:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :film

  validates :review_text, :presence => { :message => "Please enter a review"}
  validates :review_text, :length =>   {:maximum => 2000, :message => "The review must not exceed 2000 characters"} 
  validates :review_text, length: { maximum: 2000 }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you might want to add a custom validation method. Something like:

```
validate :text_must_be_decent

def text_must_be_decent
  if review_text.include?(... list of forbidden words...)
    errors.add(:review_text, 'Wash your mouth out with soap!')
  end
end
```

See also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

Comment: This doesn't really work, it will only allow one work in your 'list of forbidden words'

Comment: Right, you'd need to customize that validation message to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Another easier option is to use the [Obscenity](https://github.com/tjackiw/obscenity) gem.

1. Add the following to the Gemfile:

   ```
   gem 'obscenity'
   ```
2. Execute in the terminal:

   ```
   bundle install
   ```
3. Modify your Review model this way:

   ```
    class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :film

      validates :review_text, :presence => { :message => "Please enter a review" }

      validates :review_text, :length => { :maximum => 2000, :message => "The review must not exceed 2000 characters" }
      validates :review_text, obscenity: true
    end
   ```

And that's it. The project is not longer maintained since 2016, but I'm using it on production with rails 6 and it still works.

Answer (score 0):

it's really doesn't work like that with validate , and i should know i tried it your way Matt.

to create a custom validate you need to create a class like that :

```
    class myValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
      def validate(record)
        if record.review_text.present?
         @review_text = record.review_text.dup
         @review_text.downcase!

     @bad_keywords = ["bad_word","another_bad_word",....]
     @bad_keywords.each do |word|  
     if @review_text.include? word
      record.errors[:review_text] << 'Wash your mouth out with soap!'
    end
    end


   end
end
end
```

and inside your model :

```
 include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates_with myValidator
```

you can put "myValidator" inside your model or you can put it in the lib dir